# Java Web + Active Directory - Single Sign-on

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

How can i use Java EE to get informations from the computer, like username, and verify in a Active Directory permissions and the profile of the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ok with working NTLM v1 / v2 protocols, then you can use [**jcifs**](https://jcifs.samba.org/) library which is open-source and completely free. Setup is very simple:

1 - Add below filter configuration into web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>NtlmAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jcifs.http.domainController</param-name>
        <param-value>ActiveDirectoryIP</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jcifs.smb.client.domain</param-name>
        <param-value>DomainName</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jcifs.smb.client.laddr</param-name>
        <param-value>LocalMachineIP</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jcifs.smb.client.username</param-name>
        <param-value>YourUsernameHere</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jcifs.smb.client.password</param-name>
        <param-value>YourPassHere</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>NtlmAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/ntlm/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

2 - Create URI which need to make sign-on authentication, something like */rest/ntlm/auth* as our ntlm filter needs to be triggered before coming to controller method.

3 - Get user information using below line of code, which will return something like DOMAINNAME\accountname:

```
String username = httpServletRequest.getRemoteUser();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll check it out

Comment: It should work definitely, don't forget to accept this answer afterwards.

Comment: This feature has been deprecated for *years*. See the blue text listed as IMPORTANT at the top of this page: https://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/ntlmhttpauth.html. Short answer: use Jespa.